# "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to..."

Tags: php, mysql

I know that every week someone asks the same question, but I also noticed that the solution(and the problem) is always different.

I'm getting the MySQL error :

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''patients' (id,name,birthyear) VALUES (2, 'Itzik Karasik', '1997')' at line 1**

It's not the first time I'm getting this error, but still I can;t find the problem in the query. the query is:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'patients' (id,name,birthyear) 
        VALUES ($id, '$name', '$birthyear')";
```

and the final query (I echoed the `$query`):

```
INSERT INTO 'patients' (id,name,birthyear) VALUES (2, 'Itzik Karasik', '1997')
```

the `patients` table has 3 fields:

1. id - bigint
2. name - varchar
3. birthyear - varchar

Comment: use `patients` instead of `'patients'`

Comment: Don't quote your table name.  It makes it think it's a string.  If you want to do that, you need to use backticks, not single quotes ``INSERT INTO `patients` (id,name,birthyear) VALUES(...)``.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **"What"** worked? @ReuvenKarasik many answers below and none were accepted as being the correct one(s)

Comment: Indeed.  Please mark an answer below as "the" answer (by clicking the hollow check mark).  It provides helpful feedback to the community.

Comment: First of all, I tried to mark @watchers's answer as the answer but it told me that I have to wait 11 minutes :(

second, how can I mark a comment like this one as the answer?

third, when I wrote the "thanks, it worked" there was only one comment. at the same moment 3 other people commented and then my comment was published after 4 other comments.

Comment: Try and pay attention to initial "comments" underneath your question. They can prove to be just as useful than actual given answers. Where I posted comments to you, but never bothered answering and were indeed relevant to your issue. @ReuvenKarasik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't quote table names.  Escape them with the backtick (`` ` ``) if you need to.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO patients (id , name , birthyear) 
    VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$birthyear')";
```

Comment: @Alireza Fallah (As per your comment in your edit) - How do we know for sure that `$id` needs to be quoted? There's another answer given with quoted `$id` where the OP states *"I've tried, but it didn't work"* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030411/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to/21030425#comment31614474_21030440

Comment: @Fred -ii- You're assuming `id` is a numeric field.  It might not be.

Comment: I also had a feeling about that earlier, and where I did comment to the OP to use quotes around `$id`, yet the OP shows in the question, that the `id` column is a `bigINT` @Lotharyx and I deleted my comment about it.

Comment: it doesn't matter if id is `bigINT` , but it might not be

Comment: If it is numeric, it does no harm to quote it--mysql understands that a quoted number in a numeric field is a number.  If it's not numeric, the quotes are likely needed.

Comment: I guess everyone who have given answers are all 50% right and 50% wrong ;-) the OP has since vanished into thin air, so it seems. Never a response from any of my comments. A real `"Fly-by-Night"` case; shame.

Comment: looks like together we were a bit more than 50% right :) thanks for the edits

Comment: 50% right is indeed the better side ;-) @watcher cheers

Comment: I said on the question that id is a bigint field. good to know that I can qoute the value anyway though .. ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's how I would do it:

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO `patients` (`id`,`name`,`birthyear`) 
            VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$birthyear')";
```

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't work

Comment: Then also add: VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$birthyear')";

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What error message(s) are you getting? @ReuvenKarasik and make sure also, that you're well in fact connected to your DB.

Comment: I was getting the same error. 
anyway now I solved it thanks to @watcher and Alireza Fallah

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
   $query = " INSERT INTO patients (id,name,birthyear) VALUES 
    ({$id}, '{$name}', '{$birthyear}') ";
```

Comment: The curly braces around variables is completely unnecessary in this case.